# OAuth2 client_id retrieve, not from console

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I'm trying to use OAuth2 for this API https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects/addFirebase

I understand client_id can be retrieved in the credentials part in Google Cloud Console, but there is not way to retrieve this programatically?

Service account can be retrieved programatically like this:

```
gcloud beta iam service-accounts create "${SERVICE_ACCOUNT}"
```

Why there is no equivalent for OAuth client_id?

Answer (score 1):

No, the Client ID and Client Secret are downloaded as JSON files from the Google Cloud Console. There is no published (public) API do to this.